# CSS - Three Scrollable Equal-Height Main Content Columns (Fluid-Height) and Sticky/Always-Visible Footer

Tags: html, css

I've looked at practically all the posts here and on Google and can't seem to find the answer to my CSS layout question about "3 equal-height columns with a 'really' sticky footer", with the layout requirements as follows:

1. Top Header section, with a row for drop-down Menu options and another row for Toolbar buttons.
2. Main Content section, with 3 equal-height columns. The center column will have liquid width, the left and right columns will have fixed widths. All 3 columns will have fluid/variable heights, and EACH COLUMN will automatically show/use its own Scroll Bar if there is more content than will fit in the available, visible content area of the column. In other words, the columns should NOT push down the "sticky" Footer section below them if any column has long content, but instead show/use a Scroll Bar for the user to scroll through content.
3. Footer section (sticky/fixed), which must ALWAYS be visible at the bottom of the window/viewport regardless of the length of the content in any of the 3 columns in the Main Content section. The footer should not be pushed down by any of the 3 columns above it, and must be really "sticky" and always visible on the viewport.

I've literally spent weeks looking for an answer, but all the solutions I've seen about the "(Three) Equal-Height Columns with Sticky Footer" do not prevent the Main Content section columns from "pushing" the Footer down if there's long content in any of the content columns.

I really hope someone can help with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Keoki, Thanks for showing interest in answering my question. Actually, I don't have HTML/CSS code yet that I can show you. What I have right now is a handwritten mockup of the layout that I need, for which I'm looking for an HTML/CSS model or template I can use.

Comment: Hi Keoki, I know enough of HTML and CSS to code a simple layout, but I'm unable to code this particular layout:

1. Top Header - contains 2 rows (text menu options, toolbar buttons)

2. Content Area - 3 equal-height columns (2 fixed-width sidebars each containing 2 panels, and a fluid-width content column in the middle holding a textarea). If any column has long content, it will automatically show a scroll bar for scrolling up/down (instead of pushing the "sticky" footer down).

3. Footer - an always-visible, "sticky" footer that's not pushed down by the content columns above.

Thanks Keoki.

Comment: The question is quite clear, and I think NGLN has the answer (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/R6F5q/2/.

Tested on Win7 in IE7, IE8, IE9, Opera 11, FF 4, Chrome 12, SafariWin 5.

Comment: Thanks a bundle @NGLN! Unbelievably cool code! I can't believe it can look so simple, and yet I realize such clean and clear clode can only come from someone who's been deep in the CSS trenches. I'm marking it as answered, although I do have a follow-up question (about the 'textarea' portion of my question) which you can answer at your convenience: I'll use a fluid-width and fluid-height 'textarea' in the center column that'll be attached to CKEditor. Any suggestion how to code the fluid height of an initially-empty, auto-scrollable textarea that fills the entire height of the center column?

Comment: @Oscar P. Normally, you should ask a new question. But I think, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/R6F5q/3/) is what you want.

Comment: Thanks NGLN, I appreciate you much. I was able to make a few changes to the CSS so the textarea fills the entire center area and works with Firefox, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/OneFlip/U747F/. Thanks again!