# CSS -- two columns, one static, the other scrollable and maxed out to the first's height

Tags: html, css

I've had trouble finding resources on how to do this. ([This](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395501/css-three-scrollable-equal-height-main-content-columns-fluid-height-and-stic) didn't seem to work in my case). I want two columns, side by side, of equal height -- determined by the right column's height.

Both of their heights should be variable, and if the contents of the left are taller than those of the right, then the left column should be scrollable.

I've tried making the left column absolutely positioned, but then it just overflows the container, even if its overflow is set to scroll. I'd set a max-height, but I want max height to be dynamically set by the right column.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You will definitely need javascript to make this work if you want complete cross-browser compatibility. Are you looking to target all browsers, or just modern ones?

Comment: All. OK. Guess I'll use JS, then.

Answer (score 0):

Default styles will work for the right column.

For the left one:

```
.left-column {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And you need this little jQuery snippet to make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var desiredHeight = $('.right-column').height();
    $('.left-column').css('max-height',desiredHeight);
    $('.left-column').css('min-height',desiredHeight);
});
```

It works fine when your page loads. if the content would change even after the page is loaded, then you have to bind the code above to a event (which changes the content).

Hope it helps you.